# Rails action/fragment cache only if admin user is not logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to disable action/fragment caching when an "admin" user is logged in (like when current_user.role = "admin")?

I use caching on my site, but when an admin user is logged in, I add some extra links to certain things which are cached. The amount of admin traffic is really minimal so I would only like to cache what the normal user sees. When an admin is logged in I basically want caching to be turned off for him.

I am NOT asking about full-page caching, only fragment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using this helper now, instead of the "cache" helper:

```
  def cache_unless_admin *args
      m = args.shift
      if cannot? :manage, m
        cache args do
          yield
        end
      else
        yield
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Rails 4, you can use the CacheHelper :

```
<%= cache_unless admin?, project do %>
  <b>All the topics on this project</b>
  <%= render project.topics %>
<% end %>
```

[Rails 4 CacheHelper doc](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionView/Helpers/CacheHelper%3acache_unless)